# Meaning of 'inertial term'

Tags: noise, textbook-erratum

I'm working through a textbook and it includes the equation

$m \ddot{x} + m \gamma \dot{x} = \frac{-du}{dx}+\xi(t) $.

It says that we can "neglect the inertial term" from this for the next step. Which is the inertial term, and why is it called that?

Comment: This kind of depends upon context.  For instance, in the Navier-Stokes equation, some refer to the $\mathbf{v} \cdot \nabla \mathbf{v}$ term as the inertial term.

Comment: The second term $m\gamma \dot x$ is sometimes called the resistive term and a third term which depends on $x$ the stiffness term.  In that sort of equation in electricity The terms might be called  inductive, resistive and capacitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your expression, the term $m\ddot x$ is the "inertial term".

It describes the force needed to accelerate ($\ddot x$) the mass $m$. Hence, "inertial".

It can be neglected if you know that that term is small compared to other terms in the expression (for example, the velocity term with $\dot x$ in it). That depends on the context.

Answer (score 1):

If $x$ is displacement and $m$ represents mass and the mass is traveling at near constant velocity, then the acceleration is small, so the first term may be neglected.